# CSS: Is it possible to make the horizontal cells in a table row line up verically?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Background: I have a client whose website was built by someone else in an old obscure framework that I can't clearly identify by looking through the files. The site has several pages of tabular data used by member organizations.

Structural Challenge: They want to iframe the content tables into another system. The iframe is working fine, but the tables are too wide for mobile. I could force the tables into a smaller width using CSS, but that would make the information unusable.

Question: I know how to make divs line up in a tabular form. Is it possible, through CSS, to make the `<td>` in a row line up underneath each other instead of beside each other, in an outline type hierarchy?

Comment: If you google "responsive tables" or "mobile friendly tables" you can find a host of very robust and nice looking solutions.

Comment: Looks like I was using the wrong search terms. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can make them `display: block;`

```css
td {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure about the browser support for this, but you can make the `tr`'s a `flex-column`.

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I will give that a try and report back on the success. The site hasn't been published for the public yet, or I would post a link.